# Using KotlinPoet, is it possible to add a `@field:SomeAnnotation`?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I am writing a KSP processor and I want to create a class that has a property which is annotated like this:

```
class MyClass {
  @field:Annotation
  var myProperty: MyType
}
```

Is that currently possible?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution myself:

```
AnnotationSpec.builder(Annotation::class)
        .useSiteTarget(AnnotationSpec.UseSiteTarget.FIELD)
        .build()
```